# Magento2 localization

Tags: localization, magento2

I've following files in /app/code/magento/xx_xx

```
composer.json
language.xml
registration.php
LICENSE.txt
LICENSE_AFL.txt
```

Following command creates from my translated all-modules-strings-file a directory structure /vendor/magento/module-backend/i18n/xx_YY.csv for all modules

```
magento i18n:pack --mode=merge -d xx_YY.csv . xx_YY
```

Where should this directory-structure situate and how to get it work?

Comment: See [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/module-file-structure.html#language-package-file-structure). It looks like your directory structure is correct, what issue are you seeing?

Comment: If it's used one csv-file with all 11 000 translation strings which is done by magento i18n:collect-phrases -command and translated, it is situated same /app/code/magento/xx_xx folder and translation works fine. But, if that one csv-file is changed to many folders by magento i18n:pack -command and all those folders situate in same folder (/app/code/magento/xx_xx) with composer.json etc. then translation doesn't work at all.

Comment: The behavior you describe sounds expected. The `i18n:pack` command is supposed to create a language package for a single locale. But if you're trying to set up something like [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/app/i18n/Magento), it should also work. For one thing, I believe that it's still true that for now the entire path must be all-lowercase. I believe that in 2.1, you can use ISO paths like `es_ES`. In any case, I hope this helps.